# How to bypass keycloak consent screen for ext-idm users if user already present in keycloak and want to link automatically

Tags: keycloak

We have configured a SAML based ext-idp with keycloak. Now we are trying to onboard users from ext-idm to keycloak. Usecase is, same user is already present in keycloak and same user is trying to login from ext-idm. Now keycloak is showing a consent page for linking the user. Is there a way to bypass this consent and link the ext-idm user to keycloak user?

For all Client Scopes in keycloak we disabled the 'Display On Consent Screen' option.
All clients 'Consent Required' is disabled.
Both changes did not help.

After disabling consent in Client scope we expected ext-idm users auto link with keycloak user. But as of now Keycloak asks for a consent before linking.

Comment: Which version of Keycloak are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Probably you changed a SAML client (SAML SP) settings but you need to change Identity Brokering (SAML IdP) settings. Please read this section:

https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_admin/index.html#automatically-link-existing-first-login-flow